# Curvature flow for convex planes curves

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Tentative translation of the original question.** I've read several articles on the curvature flow for convex plane curves (the curve remains convex during evolution, and eventually shrinks to a point). I found this result interesting but couldn't relate it to a real life phenomenon. Does anyone know of a real phenomenon which could shed some light on this result?

**Original question.** 
Bonsoir mes amis, j'ai lu plusieurs articles sur le flot de courbure pour le cas des courbes convexes planes (pendant l’évolution la courbe reste convexe et tend vers un point à la limite), je l'ai trouvé très intéressant mais je n'ai pas pu appliquer un exemple dans notre vie pratique ou un certain phénomène déroulant dans la nature qui explique ce flot et cette évolution. Est-ce que quelqu'un a une idée d'un certain exemple ou phénomène réel qui explique ce résultat ??

Comment: Pouvez-vous traduire votre question en anglais?

Comment: Je ne vois pas comment un phénomène ou un exemple réel pourrait expliquer un résultat mathématique. Cherches-tu une application de cette théorie ou s'agit-il d'autre chose ? [Je veux bien traduire la question en anglais, mais il faudrait déjà que je sois sûr de bien la comprendre...]

Comment: @PseudoNeo, the translation need not be perfect. The original version can be included in the question so that the OP's intention is not washed out in the translation.

Comment: i've read several articles on the curvature flow for convex plane curves written by Hamilton and Gage, i really liked the subject and i tried to find an example of some real experiment going on in nature or in our real life that explains the different steps of the evolution process but i couldn't find one. Do u have any ideas or examples ?

Comment: so my problem is finding an example that explains this phenomena of evolution

Comment: I believe this kind of flow was first considered in the physics literature as a model for "grain boundaries". If you add a constant driving term (i.e. replace k with 1+k) then it can be used to model fire fronts: see e.g. http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2801&context=eispapers

Comment: @lilo Cannot recollect source, the tractrix shaped grinding stone wears out retaining its shape.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about plane curves, but here's an example.

In 1974, Firey introduced a model to describe the evolution of a stone submitted to abrasive processes (itself a step on the very old question of understanding the shape of pebbles). The model boils down to a (Gauss) curvature flow. In 1999, Ben Andrews proved the 2D equivalent of the evolution result you quoted: under the curvature flow, every (strictly) convex surface remains convex and (after rescaling) converges to a sphere.

So, in a way, the evolution of pebbles is a real life phenomenon related to curvature flows.

You can find more information on this kind of questions in chapter VII of Marcel Berger's *Geometry Revealed*.

**VF.** Voici un élément de réponse, qui ne concerne cependant pas les courbes planes.

En 1974, Firey introduisit un modèle pour décrire l'évolution d'une pierre soumise à l'abrasion (ce qui est une étape vers la compréhension de la forme des galets, une question remontant à la plus haute Antiquité). Le modèle n'est rien d'autre qu'un flot de courbure (de Gauss). En 1999, Ben Andrews a démontré l'équivalent bidimensionnel du résultat que tu as cité : sous le flot de courbure, les surfaces strictement convexes restent strictement convexes et convergent (modulo renormalisation) vers la sphère.

Ainsi, la formation des galets est un exemple de phénomène de la Vie Réelle™ lié aux flots de courbure.

Tu trouveras plus d'information à ce sujet au chapitre VII du (magnifique) *Géométrie vivante* de Marcel Berger.

Comment: Thnak you @PseudoNeo for ur explanation, I see that this example can be explained by th mean curvature flow or the ricci flow cz w're working in 3 dimensional space

Answer (score 0):

The physical model underlying these works is of a rubber band in molasses. I believe that Matt Grayson explains it this way in his paper solving Hamilton's curve flow conjecture.

To be precise, first imagine that the rubber band is entirely constrained from moving, by *infinitely* thick molasses. The force field along the rubber band that is generated by the rubber band's own tension is identical to the curvature vector field. Now, allowing infinitesmal motion of the rubber band by reducing the thickness from infinite to $1 / \text{infinitesmal}$, the actual derivative of the motion of the rubber band is exactly the motion of the curvature flow.

Comment: thank u Lee Mosher this explains the evolution process but this an example that we have made and illustrate to explain this evolution  but it's not a phenomenon in nature or real life that happens spontaneously

Comment: @lilo: Then you should clarify your original question, which did not ask for "spontaneity".

Comment: u are right @Lee mosher thank u for ur remark :)